# get-pnplistitem use title instead of internal name

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm new to get-pnplistitem, so forgive my ignorance on this.

I've got a list in Sharepoint that we want to pull down and do some things with. I'm using the CAML query to get just the new requests in the list. My basic code for that is:

```
$url = "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/dept"
$listQuery = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>New</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"

Connect-PnPOnline -URL $url -Credentials pnpconnectuser

$requests = Get-PnPListItem -List "List Name" -Query $listQuery
```

Which seems to be working. I can see that $requests contains the two items in my test list. But my fields have some very odd internal names:

[image]

When I need to do some things with that data, how do I reference the values by their human readable column names? For instance, "FirstName" instead of "Title". Or "Department" instead of "etaj".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, when getting specific field name, it should be using field internal name instead of display name.

For example when there is a space in the field "test space", the internal name will covert to "test_x0020_space".

Comment: Thank you. I ended up recreating the whole list so the internal names would be readable. I think the original list was created automatically from a form, hence the weird names. Much easier now with names that make sense.